# How to make a vertical menu so that the other menus go down with its expansion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menubar

I want to create a vertical menu like when I click the parent menu the children expand below the parent and it pushes down the other parent menus in html,css and js. Would be grateful! thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want to say this
**[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/VE4DP/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="SlideMenu1">
<ul>
   <li class="SlideMenu1_Folder"><div><a>FOLDER 1</a></div><span><!-- empty --></span>
      <ul style="display:none">
         <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="SlideMenu1_Folder"><div><a>FOLDER 2</a></div><span><!-- empty --></span>
      <ul style="display:none">
         <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="SlideMenu1_Folder"><div><a> FOLDER3</a></div><span><!-- empty --></span>
      <ul style="display:none">
         <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The Css

```
#SlideMenu1 ul
{
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 13px;
}
#SlideMenu1 li
{
   cursor: pointer;
}
#SlideMenu1 li div
{
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
   background-color: #A0A0A0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #A0A0A0;
   position: relative;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 95px;
}
#SlideMenu1 li div:hover
{
   background-color: #666666;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #666666;
}
#SlideMenu1 li a
{
   color: #EEEEEE;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
}
#SlideMenu1 li a:hover
{
   color: #EEEEEE;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
}
#SlideMenu1 li li
{
   cursor: auto;
   padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
   margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
   background-color: #EEEEEE;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#SlideMenu1 li li a
{
   color: #666666;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
}
#SlideMenu1 li li:hover
{
   background-color: #C0C0C0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#SlideMenu1 li li a:hover
{
   color: #666666;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
}
#SlideMenu1
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 104px;
   height: 186px;
   z-index: 0;
}
```

The Java Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(".SlideMenu1_Folder div").click(function()
   {
      if ($(this).parent().find('ul').is(':hidden'))
      {
         $(this).parent().find('ul').show();
      }
      else
      {
         $(this).parent().find('ul').hide();
      }
   });
});
</script>
```